# Referencing a local gem with RVM and Bundler?

Tags: ruby, git, rvm, bundler

I want to work on a supporting library while building an application while using RVM and Bundler to manage my application environment.

In my Gemfile is

```
# forked and cloned to local directory
gem 'feedzirra', :path => '../../feedzirra'
```

Then on command line:

```
$ bundle install
..
Using feedzirra (0.2.0.rc2) from source at /Users/ryan/dev/feedzirra 
..
$ bundle show feedzirra
/Users/ryan/dev/feedzirra
$ gem which feedzirra
ERROR:  Can't find ruby library file or shared library feedzirra
```

irb:

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > require 'feedzirra'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- feedzirra
    from /Users/ryan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/ryan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/ryan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to run it in context of bundler:

```
bundle exec gem which feedzirra
```

or

```
bundle exec irb
```